# Scheme string-ref and char-whitespace? using

Tags: string, scheme, substring

```
(define len (string-length "James ApR23Trb&%25G)(=?vqa"))    

(define (divide-string str)
          (let (x)
            (if (char-whitespace? (string-ref str x))
             (substring str (+ 1 x) (- len 1))
             (printf "an invalid input!"))
             ))
(divide-string "James ApR23Trb&%25G)(=?vqa")
```

> I have a string with divided into a blank space. I need to handle two
>   substring. One is till blank space and the other one is from blank
>   space. But i could not handle the index of blank space with x.
>
> ```
> Any help will be appraciated. Thank you even now.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try `regexp-split`:

```
> (regexp-split #rx"\\s" "James ApR23Trb&%25G)(=?vqa")
'("Jame" " ApR23Trb&%25G)(=?vqa")
```

Here `\\s`  matches whitespace.

Oops. I mistook the question for a Racket question.

In a Scheme implementation: search for `split` in the documentation 
and see what your implementation of choice has available.